# Sudden deflation of a mountain bike tube without a bang?

Tags: mountain-bike, tire, innertube, puncture

I pumped up my flat tires on a Sunday afternoon and on Monday nothing went wrong, but on Tuesday, my bike was left in the rain followed by scorching sun. During that time, both of my bike tires deflated suddenly but there was no puncture or bang.

It is confirmed that the tube had a hole.

Any explanation for why it happened?

Comment: I'm guessing a hole in the tube.  If you rode on wet streets that often makes it easier for glass shards to do damage.  And heat increases tire pressure which can provoke a failure if you're missing a rim strip or some such.  Check:  Where on the tube is the hole -- inside or outside?  Next to the valve?

Comment: Personally I find that sudden deflation like that is usually due to a loose valve core

Comment: Another possible cause is a malicious person with a needle, or a compass for drawing circles.  Was the hole on the outside, inside, or sidewall area of the tube?  Was it small and round or a short slot?   Did you check the tyre/rim at that point for a cause?

Comment: I would be careful about jumping to conclusions around the rain and sun being related to this.

Comment: Why were the tyres flat in the first place? That's probably more significant than the weather.

Answer (score 2):

You say that both tyres deflated suddenly and you pumped them up on Sunday from flat.

I think the sun has caused this in one of maybe two ways. If both tyres were flat on Sunday because they had slow punctures, then when they were out in the sun all that time, they got hot and the pressure increased. That increased pressure made the slow punctures into much faster punctures until all the air was gone.

Or... one or both tubes were fine, but the heat from the "scorching sun" simply caused both tubes to go flat by heating up a section until something gave way. The only surprise is that you didn't hear a bang in this scenario, which would make it seem less likely.

Lesson: leave your bike in the shade.

In either case, you want make sure that there is nothing sharp left in the set up to cause further punctures. Check the rim strip to see that it is in good condition. Check the tubes to find out where the holes are. This can help narrow the search for the sharp object (that's why people line up the valve with the tyre branding). check the tyre and remove any sharp objects. Replace tyres if they are getting too thin to stop punctures.